# jQuery function for app style slide in menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

My name is Adam, I'm new to Stack Exchange, but have found this site very useful for many past problems I have had.

I'm having a problem with a jquery function and thought I'd seek advice here. I have a pretty decent knowledge of html & css, a little of php, but virtually none of javascript or jquery.

I'm currently working on a site that uses specific html tags to enable dynamic content as php isn't permitted. Javascript is however so I've been looking it. I don't have a live example to show you here as I can only preview the design from within my account, however I have pasted the script below.

I wanted to create a responsive design, fluid down to mobile. Following recent design trends, I wanted to create 'Slide in/out' style menus from the side of the screen (think Facebook Mobile, Dolphin Browser). After viewing some examples, I wrote a function which altered the CSS, moving the main div#site template to the right, revealing the left menu. Everything was ok and it worked fine.

Today I decided it would be nice to have 2 slide out menus, one on the left, the other, on the right.

I added to the function what I thought was going to work, and it sort of does.

I have a button (with class .open-sidebar-right) to slide the main site (div#site) to the left, revealing the right hand menu. I can then click either the same button or the div#site to close the menu.

The problem occurs when I click on the left button. The left menu opens and closes absolutely perfectly, however it renders the right button totally useless and doesn't function at all.

I've tried writing it as two separate functions, using one variable for both menus with different values, and it always renders the right button useless after using the left button.

As I mentioned earlier, I have virtually no knowledge of Javascript or jQuery, so it's probably poorly coded, but I can't understand why this wouldn't work.

If anyone has any advice or suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance, Adam.

```
jQuery(function () {
var sidebarleft;
var sidebarright;

// ------------
// Left sidebar

jQuery(".open-sidebar-left").click(function () {
    if (!sidebarleft) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'left':'50%',
        });
        sidebarleft = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'left':'0%',
        });
        sidebarleft = false;
        return false;
    }
});

// ------------
// Right sidebar

jQuery(".open-sidebar-right").click(function () {
    if (!sidebarright) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'right':'50%',
        });
        sidebarright = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery("#site").css({
           'right':'0%',
        });
        sidebarright = false;
        return false;
    }
});

// ----------------------------------
// Close sidebars by clicking on site

jQuery("#site").click(function () {
    if (sidebarleft) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'left':'0%',
        });
        sidebarleft = false;
        return false;
    } else if (sidebarright) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'right':'0%',
        });
        sidebarright = false;
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Adam, quick note, Welcome to SE and also you should try to make your questions simpler; basically stating, "here's what I am trying to do, here's my code that I have tried, here is my error/ why isn't this working."

Comment: Also, this is a good candidate for a jsfiddle so people can more easily see what's going on.

Comment: And what are your `sidebarleft` and `sidebarright` variables? You declared them but you didn't define them. So when you say `if(!sidbarright)` it doesn't know what it's looking for because `sidebarright/left` isn't true or false, it's only referencing an `undefined` value. I would at least automatically set both `sidebar*` variables to `false`, that way in your conditional statement (if) it happens automatically. But even better would be to target a query to your sidebar object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, the problem seems to be a CSS issue.

When you click your left button your click event is adding an inline style to your #site div like so:

```
<div id="site" style="left:50%;">
```

Then when you click your right button your code appends the new style to your #site div like so:

```
<div id="site" style="left: 0%; right: 50%;">
```

See the problem?

To fix this you must do two things. Since you didn't post your CSS, I don't know how you have your `#site` styled, but remove any `left` or `right` style from your `#site` style declaration.

Next update your jQuery code to remove any previous inline styles like so:

```
 // ------------
// Left sidebar

jQuery(".open-sidebar-left").click(function () {
    jQuery("#site").removeAttr('style');
    if (!sidebarleft) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'left':'50%',
        });
        sidebarleft = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'left':'0%',
        });
        sidebarleft = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

AND

```
jQuery(".open-sidebar-right").click(function () {
    jQuery("#site").removeAttr('style');
    if (!sidebarright) {
        jQuery("#site").css({
            'right':'50%',
        });
        sidebarright = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery("#site").css({
           'right':'0%',
        });
        sidebarright = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

`removeAttr` is your friend here.  Also you may want to use an animate instead of just changing the css values, but thats your call

[jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks for your help zgood, it was the style attributes that were causing the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Adam,

@zgood says your code is good, but I thought I'd point out a few errors and make some suggestions which may solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // in the jQuery doc, they don't suggest you use $(<func>)
    var sidebarleft = false, // sidebarleft and sidebarright has to be equal to something
    sidebarright = false; // either true or false (I would use false since you're testing false in your conditional

    $(".open-sidebar-left").click(function() {
        if( !sidebarleft ) {
             $("#site").css({
                 left: '50%' // remove the comma, and do not put quotes around single-word identifiers
             });
             sidebarleft = true; 
             return false;
        } else {
           $("#site").css({
              left: '0'
           });
           sidebarleft = false;
           return false;
        }
    });

    $(".open-sidebar-right").click(function() {
        if( !sidebarright ) {
             $("#site").css({
                 right: '50%' // remove the comma, and do not put quotes around single-word identifiers
             });
             sidebarright = true; 
             return false;
        } else {
           $("#site").css({
              right: '0'
           });
           sidebarright = false;
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```

So as you can see in the comments in the code above,

1. jQuery says it's valid, but not suggested that you use `jQuery(function(){});` so query the `document` element then test for ready, then call a function
2. `sidebarright` and `sidebarleft` were `undefined` (neither true or false) so your
   if statements don't make sense.
3. In the `css()` declaration, you shouldn't put a comma on the last element. Only put commas if there are more than one element.

I would also suggest using `animate()` instead of `css()`, and also (if you're using Chrome) use the inspector and (if you're using Firefox) use FireBug to test for any errors in your javascript code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the above code is written much better. I said it was good because it wasn't producing any errors (although that comma would have made IE freak out)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I've decided to go with animate now, and just alter the left position, works perfectly.

Comment: If my solution is the one that fixed the problem why did you mark this one as the solution? This could be confusing for people visiting this question for an answer in the future. The above is just a code critique.